# How to select the values from a map whose keys can be intersected with a given range - c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map and its keys have consisted of pairs.
And, I have a given range and need to find all the values from the map, whose keys are intersecting with the given range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void printMap(map<pair<int, int>, char> &my_map)
{
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    for(auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << " key : ( " << it->first.first << ", " << it->first.second << " ) - value : " << it->second << endl;
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    map<pair<int, int>, char> my_map;
    my_map.insert({{1,4}, 'a'});
    my_map.insert({{6,8}, 'b'});
    my_map.insert({{7,10}, 'c'});
    my_map.insert({{14,16}, 'd'});
    my_map.insert({{18,23}, 'e'});

//printMap(my_map);

/*
 I have a range (7, 9) and I need to take all the values from the map, whose keys are intersecting with the given range.
 In here, (6, 8) and (7, 10) are intersect candidates of given (7, 9).
 then I need the outcome as,
    'b'
    'c'
*/

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? (without iterating the map manually...)

Comment: If you care about performance, then you need a more sophisticated data structure. If you don't, just iterate keys, and check that first value *or* second value is inside the desired range

Comment: Please define "manually". I guess you could utilize the `lower_bound` method to find the starting point and then from it manually iterate back and forward. Unless you're able to provide a custom comparison operator of course (not sure if it's even possible here). Besides - are you sure you want this kind of data structure you've presented, not an interval map of some sort?

Comment: In the general case you would have to traverse the entire map, because the intervals can be literally anything.  I would consider that "iterating the map manually" is indeed the simple way to do this unless there are other special rules regarding your intervals that you haven't told us.

Comment: In other words: Your pairs describe a (start, stop) range. You need to find all entries overlapping this range. Are the ranges inclusive? Does (0, 1) overlap with (1, 2)?